# How to hover on list children items in React (and change parent state) without slowing everything down?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, hover, setstate

I have a list of items and then map pins that correspond to those items. When one hover on the list, the map icon opens. This is the way many popular maps work. The user hovers on the list item and the map changes color or an info window pops open. Take gmaps for example: 
[image]

But the way I have this setup in React currently just isn't working. So I have a parent list:

```
    <div className={classes.parentList}>
  {filtereditems.map((item, index) => (
    <ShowCard
      key={index}
      item={item}
      setCardMarkerHover={this.setCardMarkerHover}
      resetCardMarkerHover={this.resetCardMarkerHover}
    />
  ))}
</div>;
```

Then, within my List items, I call the prop functions like so

```
onMouseEnter={e => props.setCardMarkerHover(item.node.id)}
onMouseLeave={e => props.resetCardMarkerHover()}
```

These functions `setCardMarkerHover` and `resetCardMarkerHover` call setState, which then rerenders everything(!) so that my map markers change. The infowindow pops open on the right marker.

Here are the functions:

```
  setCardMarkerHover = id => {
    this.setState({
      hoveredCardId: id,
    })
  }

  resetCardMarkerHover = () => {
    this.setState({
      hoveredCardId: "",
    })
  }
```

`hoveredCardId` then gets passed to the Map and Markers (pins), and they change according to whether that marker matches the same index/id for the list items being hovered.

The challenge, as you can likely imagine, is that this really bogs my list down. It no longer scrolls smoothly because so many parts of the DOM are having to repaint/rerender as the mouse enters and exits the different list items.

React-virtualized solves this problem through `windowing` but this seems like extreme overkill.

What would another way to be able to hover on a child list item and have it change something else in another child component without triggering so much repainting?

Comment: So to properly understand your problem it'd be interesting to see the higher level part of your architecture: how you handle if the marker for a specific card needs to be shown or not (Redux, local state, etc). But potentially you might have to be more precise in the way you handle hide/show, either at each component level if it makes sense, or globally but with containers. But again, it'd be good to see the mechanic you've got in place after `props.setCardMarkerHover(item.node.id)`

Comment: @Moustachiste Do the details I added help?

Comment: I think you need to avoid the local re-render of everything by avoiding the `setState` call locally. You've got 2 options, either use the global state if you already have (or want to have) 1 with Redux for instance, and then have each `ShowCard` component connected to it and detecting if they should do something on each update, or use a Context with Provider and Customer (or useContext hook) for each component again to decide if they need to do something.